# JavaFX Exception in Main Constructor due to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, javafx, observablelist

I am new to programming JavaFx and now in my initial stages i am building an addressbook in javaFX but problem presist that It throws an exception in constructor of Main Class. 
When i use **ObserverableList** i dont get any kind of **Exception**, while when i try to use array to store Entity Objects i got Exception. 
Can anybody give me a solution to that problem?
The main thing i want to do is to **save** **ObserverableList** or **ArrayList** object to a file.

```
package com.company;
import com.company.Controllers.DatabaseConnectJDBC;      
import com.company.Controllers.MainWindowController;
import com.company.Controllers.secondWindowController;
import com.company.Model.EmployeeEntity;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main extends Application {

Stage primaryStage;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage=primaryStage;
    mainWindow();
}
public void mainWindow()  {
try{
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("Views/MainWindow.fxml"));
   AnchorPane pane=loader.load();
   Scene scene=new Scene(pane);
        MainWindowController controller=loader.getController();
        controller.setMain(this);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void secondaryWindow()  {
    try{
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("Views/secondaryWindow.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane=loader.load();
        Scene scene=new Scene(pane);
        Stage secondaryStage=new Stage();
        secondWindowController controller=loader.getController();
        controller.setMain(this,secondaryStage);
        secondaryStage.setScene(scene);
        secondaryStage.setResizable(false);
        secondaryStage.show();


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private ObservableList<EmployeeEntity> employeeObserveList= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ArrayList<EmployeeEntity> arrayList;
public ObservableList<EmployeeEntity> getEmployeeObserveList(){return employeeObserveList;}
public void setEmployeeObserveList(EmployeeEntity person){
    getEmployeeObserveList().add(person);
}

public Main()
{

    arrayList.add(new EmployeeEntity("3","126-B Millat Town","030123456","Abubaker","Usman"));
    arrayList.add(new EmployeeEntity("4","127-B Millat Town","032123456","Asma","Rasool"));
    arrayList.add(new EmployeeEntity("5","128-B Millat Town","035123456","Talha","Farooq"));

    employeeObserveList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(arrayList);
 employeeObserveList.addAll(arrayList);
}
```

**Exception**

---

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class com.company.Main
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.company.Main.<init>(Main.java:68)
    ... 13 more
```

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Doesn't seem you initialized your Arraylist ever.

Comment: I have initialized it.. u can see beneath the initialization of ObservableList

Comment: Oh i get it... Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
private ArrayList<EmployeeEntity> arrayList;
```

To

```
private List<EmployeeEntity> arrayList = new ArrayList<EmployeeEntity>();
```

You never initialized ArrayList.

Comment: Oh i get it...Thanks sir.. for helping out my problem

Comment: If it was helpful then you can up vote and accept the answer!